# How to Disable AutoMount of External Drives

Tags: rhel, automounting

Is it possible to Disable auto mount of External Harddrives or USB's in RHEL.

For security reasons I have to disable this feature.

And when I need it I will enable it back.

Comment: In nautilus? (The file manager)

Comment: I think you should manipulate udev's rules.

Comment: How about this **service autofs stop** and **chkconfig autofs off**

Comment: RHEL5 does not auto mount these (at least not on my installations) - what are you referring to? I need to right-click on a symbol on my desktop to mount any such device - after `udev` made the device appear.

Comment: @Nils Im referring to External Hard drives. Wrong RHEL 5 does automount External hard drive once you mount them atleast mine does. And how do you right click the device which is not mounted as far as I know unmounted devices doesnot appear on Desktop.

Comment: @UmairMustafa propably you did not choose "do nothing" when you first plugged in an usb-device. So this has to be a desktop-setting. First the device has to be there. Second you CAN mount it (which is probably by now your default action).

Comment: Well this Feature of asking WHAT TO DO is I believe not available in RHEL but in other Linux distros like ubuntu and mint . But yes by default External Harddrives are not automatically mounted but have to manually mount it.

Comment: @don_crissti Yes exactly this is what I want. We are using RHEL 5

Answer (score 2):

Start with `service autofs stop` and `chkconfig autofs off`. 
You can also disable GNOME's automounting with the following command:

```
gconftool-2 --direct \
    --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory \
    --type bool \
    --set /desktop/gnome/volume_manager/automount_drives false
```

If you also want to disable the automounting of media like CD/DVD drives,
you can also add:

```
gconftool-2 --direct \
    --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory \
    --type bool \
    --set /desktop/gnome/volume_manager/automount_media false
```

For further security, you can also add the following line to `/etc/modprobe.conf`:

```
install usb-storage /bin/true
```

All of this together should totally disable automounting in RHEL 5/6. 
This information comes from [The NSA's "Guide to the Secure Configuration of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5"](https://apps.nsa.gov/iaarchive/library/ia-guidance/security-configuration/operating-systems/guide-to-the-secure-configuration-of-red-hat-enterprise.cfm), section 2.2.2 ([[direct link (PDF)]](https://apps.nsa.gov/iaarchive/customcf/openAttachment.cfm?FilePath=/iad/library/ia-guidance/security-configuration/operating-systems/assets/public/upload/Guide-to-the-Secure-Configuration-of-Red-Hat-Enterprise-Linux-5.pdf&WpKes=aF6woL7fQp3dJi57Lxaa8zxUnhmRLwpcMAg4Yf#subsection.2.2.2)).